# Reshape data in a new form so that creating new columns for all possible cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

The INPUT table I got from this query and I want to get the data in the form of an output table to save it as a view for further use.

The input table is an inner join of 2 tables joined using status_code_no

Comment: Do you have a max number of repeating groups at 3?

Comment: yes there are 58 status code groups

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a hard limit of 3 repeating groups you can use conditional aggregation for this.

```
select acct_no
    , status_code_no_1 = max(case when x.RowNum = 1 then status_code_no end)
    , status_code_1 = max(case when RowNum = 1 then status_code end)
    , date_1 = max(case when RowNum = 1 then [date] end)
    , status_code_no_2 = max(case when x.RowNum = 2 then status_code_no end)
    , status_code_2 = max(case when RowNum = 2 then status_code end)
    , date_2 = max(case when RowNum = 2 then [date] end)
    , status_code_no_3 = max(case when x.RowNum = 3 then status_code_no end)
    , status_code_3 = max(case when RowNum = 3 then status_code end)
    , date_3 = max(case when RowNum = 3 then [date] end)
from
(
    select acct_no
        , status_code_no
        , status_code
        , [date]
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by acct_no order by [date])
    from MyTable
) x
group by acct_no
```

If you need more groups you can extend this code. But if you don't know how many this becomes a bit more challenging and you will need dynamic sql.